# Can't update database entry from form fields

Tags: php, sql

And this is post 3 in a few days - but I'm so close (and you guys rule).  I've got a form for 'edit' that now populates the fields with what's in the database, based on the gigid which was passed in a query.  What I can't do now is get it to update.

```
$gigid = $_GET['gigid'];

$sql="UPDATE gigs (gig_name, gig_type, gig_customer, gig_date, gig_start_time, gig_end_time,     gig_fee, gig_status, venue_name, venue_address, venue_contact) WHERE gigid=$gigid
VALUES ('$gig_name', '$gig_type', '$gig_date_created', '$gig_customer', '$gig_start_time',     '$gig_end_time', '$gig_fee', '$gig_status', '$venue_name', '$venue_address', '$venue_contact')";

else {
echo "Oops.   A gig name, gig type and customer name are required.  Did you miss one?</br>";
}
```

I keep getting the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/cp/edit_gig_process.php on line 40

I've tried every combination of doing an update I can find on the internet!  Am I doing something glaringly wrong?

Comment: When using [`UPDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) you use `SET column='$var'`, you don't use VALUES. Or replace UPDATE with `INSERT INTO gigs`. The error doesn't come from this btw, but further up probably. You're also not using `mysqli_query()`. Very unclear as a question.

Comment: An `else` statement only makese sense when following an `if` condition. Also your assignment to `$sql` is just a string operation. This does not have anything to do with a database operation. Please go through one or two of the millions of examples out there on google.

Comment: Yes, you're doing it wrong. Why don't you check correct syntax for UPDATE in sql databases? Also, you should read something about SQL injection.

Comment: You're also missing an `if` that's why you're getting that parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of problems in that statement.

**First:**

You are using where in mid of your statement

**Second:**

Update uses `set` and not `value`

**Third**

You have swapped the arguments

```
gig_customer='$gig_date_created', 
gig_date='$gig_customer',
```

i swapped them in the correct statement

The right syntax would be:

```
"update table set foo='$bar' where hello='$world'"
```

Your statement has to look like

```
$sql= "UPDATE gigs set 
      gig_name='$gig_name',
      gig_type='$gig_type', 
      gig_customer='$gig_customer', 
      gig_date='$gig_date_created', 
      gig_start_time='$gig_start_time', 
      gig_end_time='$gig_end_time',     
      gig_fee='$gig_fee', 
      gig_status='$gig_status', 
      venue_name='$venue_name', 
      venue_address='$venue_address', 
      venue_contact='$venue_contact' 
WHERE 
      gigid='$gigid'";
```

**The main problem that you have and what your error is coming from is**

`I've tried every combination of doing an update I can find on the internet! Am I doing something glaringly wrong?`

Your error tells you exactly whats wrong...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in >/home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/cp/edit_gig_process.php on line 40

I bet line 40 (see your editor) is `else{`. It expacts the right syntax.

```
//if/else statement

if($condition)
{
    //do some here
}
else
{
    //if condition fails, do some else
}
```

your are just using the else statement and missing the head `if(...){....}`

Comment: There's also a crucial function missing.

Comment: Thank you for such a helpful answer!  There was an if statement above that I accidentally didn't post but I removed it anyhow.  It's not longer firing errors, although now it's wiping the entries clean so I think I've got a problem with it not recognizing the field names or something.  I'll play around with it - thanks again.

Comment: @Topher If this answere helped you, accept it and may vote it up. According to your comment have some other problem i recommend you to ask a new question and get helped there.